# passing bash a value with leading hyphen

Tags: ruby, bash, trollop

I have a bash command that requires a string value after "-v". When this string value has a leading "-", bash tries to interpret it as a new option of the bash command rather than the value I'm trying to give for -v. Is there a way I can escape this leading hyphen? I tried
`-v -- -myValue` but then it tells me "option '-v' needs a parameter."

The command is calling a ruby file. I think this is the meaningful part of the ruby code for the purposes of this question:

```
opts = Trollop::options do
  opt :method, "Encrypt or Decrypt", :short => "m", :type => :string, :default => "decrypt"
  opt :value, "Value to Decrypt or Encrypt", :short  => "v", :type => :string, :default => ""
end
```

Comment: Perhaps if you were to tell us which bash command you were having trouble with we could offer a suggestion.

Comment: We cannot debug your option processing code without seeing it. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] of the problematic code.

Comment: It's running a ruby file. I'll modify the question to provide some of the code that may be pertinent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two conventional ways to specify arguments, but these are not enforced at the shell level, they're just tradition:

```
-v xxxx
--value=xxxx
```

Now it's sometimes possible to do:

```
-vxxxx
```

If you have a value with a dash and it's not being interpreted correctly, do this:

```
--value=-value
```

Comment: that gives me Error: invalid argument syntax: '--'.

Comment: I've adjusted this based on the [Trollop](http://manageiq.github.io/trollop/) documentation. You should be able to call `--value`. The built-in [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) is actually pretty good if Trollop can't do the job.

Answer (score -1):

```
cmd -v '-string value with leading dash'
```

### edit

```
$ cat ~/tmp/test.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 str=
 while getopts "v:" opt; do
 case "$opt" in
    v) str=$OPTARG;;
 esac
 done
 shift $(( OPTIND -1 ))

 echo "option was '$str'"
```

simple test file, my bash is GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

results:

```
chris@druidstudio:~⟫ ~/tmp/test.sh -v string
  option was 'string'
chris@druidstudio:~⟫ ~/tmp/test.sh -v -string
  option was '-string'
chris@druidstudio:~⟫ ~/tmp/test.sh -v '-string'
  option was '-string'
```

so, maybe, the bash script handling your options is not written correctly, or you have an early version of bash. As I answered in another of these silly questions earlier, clairvoyance is not one of my skills.  So, be a good chap and possibly give us, the people you are asking for help from, the pertinent information (as you state, your script is failing at the bash level, not at the ruby level, so why bother to post a ruby script?)

Comment: That still gives me the same error, interpreting the string as a new option.